# Cómo mantener clase cuando hago click y me desplazo a otro enlace, javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo un nav lateral y el cual es un template que inserto mediante php en todas mis vistas.

Estoy tratando que cuando selecciono uno de los enlaces del navegador se le ponga una clase nav-active que añada un background color y que se mantenga esa clase hasta que no haga click en otro de los enlaces del navegador.

Es posible acceder a otras vistas mediante otros enlaces dentro del enlace que se ha accedido en el navegador. Quiero seguir manteniendo el background color del navegador, para saber que se está en esa "sección".

Este es el código que estoy utilizando, pero no me funciona:

HTML:

```
 <div class="menu-items" id="menuNav">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="/posgrados">
                <div class="icon"><img src="/build/img/OfertaAcademica.png" alt="icono"></div>
                <div class="title"><span>Oferta académica</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="/alumnos">
                <div class="icon"><img src="/build/img/ALUMNOS.png" alt="icono"></div>
                <div class="title"><span>Alumnos</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="/correctores">
                <div class="icon"><img src="/build/img/CORRECTORES.png" alt="icono"></div>
                <div class="title"><span>Correctores</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="/emails">
                <div class="icon"><img src="/build/img/EMAILS.png" alt="icono"></div>
                <div class="title"><span>Emails</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item separator"></div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="/entregas?buscar=&buscar4=&buscar1=&buscar2=">
                <div class="icon"><img src="/build/img/TAREAS.png" alt="icono"></div>
                <div class="title"><span>Tareas</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="/examenes/index">
                <div class="icon"><img src="/build/img/Autoevaluacion.png" alt="icono"></div>
                <div class="title"><span>Examenes</span></div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

JS:

```
var menuNav = document.getElementById("menuNav");
var enlaces = menuNav.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var i = 0; i < enlaces.length; i++) {
   enlaces[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   var current = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-active");
   if (current.length > 0) { 
     current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" nav-active", "");
   }
   this.className += " nav-active";
   });
}
```

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido colorear un enlace clicable, pues instantes después de dicha acción el navegador te llevará a la página correspondiente. Si lo que quieres es que, una vez ya se cargue la página del enlace, este figure como activo, lo más recomendable es hacerlo directamente con PHP (en este caso) sobre la plantilla. Podrías hacerlo con Javascript recorriendo los valores de los enlaces del menú y comparándolos con el de 'window.location', pero creo que sería mejor compararlo directamente en el momento que se procesa la plantilla y no luego desde el navegador.

Comment: Exacto, lo que quiero es que se mantenga dicho enlace después de hacer click. Sin embargo, es posible acceder a otras vistas mediante otros enlaces dentro del enlace que se ha accedido en el navegador. Quiero seguir manteniendo el background color del navegador, para saber que se está en esa sección.

Comment: Para resaltar la sección que está activa, como digo, es mejor hacerlo directamente sobre la plantilla para que cuando se muestre por pantalla ya tenga la clase 'nav-active'. Ten en cuenta que lo que planteas en el código Javascript que incluiste en tu pregunta es incorporar la clase cuando haces clic, pero en ese momento la página se recarga y lo hecho antes se pierde. Edita la plantilla y añade un if en cada '<div class="item">' para que incluya la clase 'nav-active' si coincide la URL con los valores que tu quieras asignar a cada elemento del menú.

Comment: Por ejemplo, en el primer '<div class="item">' puedes hacer esto: <div class="item<?php if ($url == '/postgrados') : ?> nav--active'<?php endif; ?>">. Si resulta que ese enlace tiene que figurar como activo tanto en la página '/postgrados' como en '/prueba1', añade '/prueba1' al condicional.

Comment: Cómo puedo comparar la url del navegador con $url. Es decir, qué información tengo que poner en $url cuando la creo?

en mi código estoy poniendo esto pero no debo estar haciendolo bien:

<?php $url= null;?>
<div class="item<?php if ($url == '/posgrados') { echo ' nav--active'; } ?>"> (Esto es igual que el código que me indicabas?)

Comment: ¿Utilizas algún framework o estás programando con PHP desde cero? Los framework suelen tener métodos para obtener los slug (trozos de la URL como 'postgrados', por ejemplo). Si no usas ninguno, seguramente te sirva algo como $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Si la URL es dominio.com/postgrados/, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] devolvería '/postgrados/'.

Comment: Perfecto. Me ha funcionado y me sirve como solución a lo que buscaba. Gracias!

Comment: Otra pregunta. Cuando tengo una url que está referenciando a una id (http://localhost:2000/editar?id=21) , como podría hacer para que me sirviera dicha url a la hora de comparar urls y añadir la class?.

Comment: En lugar de utulizar algo tipo $url == '/postgrados', tendrías que recurrir a expresiones regulares o a, como en el caso concreto que indicas, comprobar si $url comienza por 'editar?id=' (sin el valor del id).

Comment: Al comprobar si $url == '/editar?id=', no lo identifica. Como sería mediante expresiones regulares? es la primera vez que escucho que existen y tras leer sobre ellas parecen realmente utiles.

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo no funciona porque estás comprobando que $url y '/editar?id=' sean iguales. Puedes comprobar si una cadena empieza por '/editar?id=' usando la función strpos. Con expresiones regulares tendrías que utilizar la función preg_match. Tienes la documentación de ambas funciones en php.net.

Comment: De acuerdo. Muchas gracias por la información. Sin duda ha sido de mucha ayuda y m está ayudando a solucionarlo.